# Github commit notification linked to wrong user, while commit linked to correct user

Tags: git, macos, github, pycharm, github-actions

Whenever I push a commit, i get a notification from github that another user has commited the changes, even though when i look at the commits in github, they are linked to my name.
Tried checking the local and global git configurations, even though everything has my username and email in it.
Why does this happen??
I use Pycharm for pushing commits via the GUI, and i use a mac.
Please do help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the email address associated with your GitHub account is different from the email address associated with your Git configuration. GitHub uses the email address in the commit metadata to link the commit to a user account, so if the email address in your commit metadata doesn't match the email address associated with your GitHub account, GitHub may not link the commit to your account.

To check the email address associated with your GitHub account, go to your GitHub profile and click on the "Edit profile" button. Then, scroll down to the "Email" section and make sure that the correct email address is listed there.

To check the email address associated with your Git configuration, open a terminal window and run the following command:

> git config --global user.email

This will display the email address currently associated with your Git configuration. Make sure that this email address matches the email address associated with your GitHub account.

If the email addresses don't match, you can update your Git configuration by running the following command:

> git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
 i had checked this out, But the email in git config is my current username, which is correct. 
I removed the git PATs stored in macos Keychain app. Which helped me out